# Adding a jar documentation to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, robotium

I downloaded the [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) jar as well as javadoc jar file. I then created a folder called libs and pasted the two jars into it. I went to properties,libraries tab and add jar and selected the main jar in my libs directory. I then tried to add the javadoc.jar to the javadoc location. It still does not show me any documentation. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4):

Follow this steps:

1. Create "robotium" directory in your project folder
2. Place "robotium-solo-4.x.jar" and "robotium-solo-4.x-javadoc.jar" to newly created "robotium" directory
3. Go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> tab Libraries, click on "Add JARs..." button on the right side and select your "robotium-solo-4.x.jar"
4. Expand "robotium-solo-4.x.jar" item on Libraries tab, double click "Javadoc location: (None)", select "Javadoc in archive" & "Workspace file" and choose "robotium-solo-4.x-javadoc.jar" for "Archive path" parameter. Click Ok.
5. Switch to "Order and Export" and check the line "robotium-solo-4.x.jar"
6. You are done!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Go to **properties**->**Java Build Path**->select tab **Order and Export**->select in the list **Robotium-solo-3.6.jar**->click on **Top** button->**Ok**